# implementing complex algorithms on database stored information

Tags: c#, sql, database, k-means

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for implementing a complex algorithm on stored information in a relational DB.

Specifically: I want to implement a variation of the k-means algorithm (a document clustering algorithm) on a large MS SQL Server database containing TFxIDF vectors of many documents (these vectors are used as input for the algorithm).

My first thought was doing the entire thing in SQL using stored procedures, functions, views and all the other basic SQL Server tools, but then I thought maybe I should write managed code (I'm fluent in C#) that will be executed on the SQL Server.

Performance is an issue here, so I need to take that in consideration also.

I would appreciate any advice on the path I should take.

Thank you!

Comment: Something to consider is that much of the new spatial operations and spatial indexing in MS SQL Server are implemented in the CLR.  Just using that as a use case example it sounds like the CLR(i.e. C# loaded as SQL CLR) might be the direction you want to go in.

Comment: you seek a solution to a mostly "undefined" problem.  There can be massive design changes based on very subtle requirements or implied factors.  Without including all or as much upfront information possible in the question, any proposed solution will just be a guess based on the assumptions of the person submitting the answer. How many rows, how often will you calculate/recalculate, what are the performance expectations, will you store the results, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Performance is an issue here

It always is.  When looking at this kind of code, there are two opposing trends that you have to consider:

- Thanks to indexing, caching, and other optimization techniques, the database server is often best positioned to make these calculation quickly.  You seem to understand this.

On the other hand:

- These calculations seldom happen in isolation.  You have to take the whole server performance into account, and your database is typically the most loaded server in your data center.  It's also the hardest to scale, both from a technical and business perspective.  Technical because you have to balance several different components, including disk, RAM, and cpu, and it's not always easy to know where your bottlenecks are.  Also, these tend to be "big" machines that not many in your organization will have experience tuning.  Finally, they don't often scale out very well.  You can't add another database server to share the load as easily as you could an application server.  From a business standpoint, all that technical mumbo jumbo adds up to cost.  More than that, the database license is itself often several thousands *per cpu*.

Take these two points together, and the best course for performance is typically to use the querying capabilities in the database to pull down just the subset of records that you really need, and maybe do some of the easier pre-processing — the low-hanging fruit, if you will.  Then finish the heavy lifting on an application server, in parallel if possible.